# Angular multi-select and jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to use Angular to make a multi-select with this dropdown:

```
http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/index5.html
```

The structure works with jQuery but when I want to add AngularJS I have problems. There is just the first level which works. Maybe It's a scope problem but I don't master it very well.

Here is a demo which works with jQuery (expand the view window to be well displayed)

```
http://jsfiddle.net/x6h54vey/
```

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('selectFilter', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "select-filter.html",
        controller: function(){
            this.filters = filters_tab;
        },
        controllerAs: "selectFilter",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // CALL PLUGIN DLMENU
        $(elem).dlmenu({
            animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-4', classout : 'dl-animate-out-4' }
        });
        }

    };
});
```

My directive template:

```
<button class="dl-trigger">Filter</button>
<ul class="dl-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="list in selectFilter.filters | orderBy: 'order'" ng-include="'field_renderer.html'"></li>
    <!-- Recursive template -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="field_renderer.html">
        <a ng-if="list.childs" href="#">{{list.name}}</a>
        <a ng-if="!list.childs" class="option" ng-class="{active: hover}" href="#">{{list.name}}</a>

        <ul ng-if="list.childs" class="dl-submenu">
            <li ng-repeat="list in list.childs | orderBy: 'order'" ng-include="'field_renderer.html'">
             </li>
        </ul>
    </script>
</ul>
```

And my demo. There is just the first level which works:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/NCLnd3DB8X7LA80J6hJE
```

In addition, don't hesitate if you have advices to optimize it.

Thank You !

Comment: A link to a jsfiddle is fine, but please also include the relevant code directly into your question.

Comment: `have problems` doesn't explain anything ... nobody can help if you aren't specific. Also if you want to change scope with external plugin events, you will need to create event callbacks to do it and use `$apply` to change scope